# Creating A Student Information System

Tags: c#, wpf, database, web, system

I am planning in creating a student information system where multiple computers can access the same server through LAN connection. The server will have a database about the students information. I pretty much have a background in creating a program similar to this but i was only able to make it for 1 computer. I don't know how to connect that database to another computer. Like for instance:

> Teacher A uses Computer 1 to access the Student Information System and
>   Teacher B uses Computer 2 to access it as well. Any modification done
>   by Teacher A will be updated to the database and it will be seen as
>   well for Teacher B.

And my other concern is whether I should make it web-based or not. I only have an experience with using WPF Application for this kind of system but someone told me that its easier if i used a web-based instead in this kind of networking idea. Can you tell me the advantages and disadvantages of using a web-based and its counterpart.

to summarize:

- How can I connect multiple computers to access a single database system.
- Which is better to use if its web-based application or desktop application.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Couple of points

1. Set up a machine for making it a server where your database will be residing. All the machines will be pointing to this server and database using LAN.
2. You can create both web based and desktop based application. I would prefer to go for web based application so that in future you can extend to access this system outside the college premises.

Answer (score 0):

Both Web based and desktop based application can work for you in this case. For  the database you can use SQlServer2008 and share this database over the LAN so that it can be accessed from all the computers in the network.

You must create one server machine for the database which will be accessed by other client machines on your LAN.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy you just need to give the ipaddress of sql machine in connection string instead of "." And every thing else will be same .

Answer (score 0):

You will have more than one solution to make the  database be used in different locations.

1- Regarding the desktop application we can setup the application on a terminal server (considering the server configurations and how many users will access the server) and the user will access the sever through the terminal service (the application will access only one database for all users in different locations.

2- The desktop application can be run in a several locations accessing a database at the same location, By using the (Database Replication) we will have an updated data in all location.

3- The application that the users access over the internet is called a (web application), it is a software that is accessed through a web browser running on client’s machine  called a web application, the application will access only one database for all users.

4- Adding a (web service) to the desktop application will allows different machines to interact with each other through a network.

The question is which is the best solution?

Option (1) is the easiest one because we don't need changing anything in the application but if the internet connection is disabled no one can access the application and if a bad internet connection then we will facing many complaints from the users.

Option(2) is good because we don't need changing anything in the application as well the database server will replicate the information with each other and update the information for all locations.

I prefer option(4) when designing a new application.

I prefer option(2) when the application is old and there is no ability to modify or it will take a lot of time to modify.